# Help with vehicles in GTA V online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I wanted to ask why it doesn't appear to me the Kraken and the Dodo in GTA V online, there aren't in the shop! Im level 71 and im Xbox One user.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those things are exclusive content for returning players from last generation. Before getting these exclusive items you must transfer your Xbox 360 or PS3 character. There is also a lot more content for returning players, so if you do have a last generation version of the game, merging it with next generation is a big advantage.